# Different outcome for the same quaternion between geometry_msgs::Pose and tf::Transform

Tags: pose, rviz, path, ros-kinetic, frames

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the code I am using to broadcast a transform and publish the path of the same transform.

```
global_transform_.frame_id_ = "world";
global_transform_.child_frame_id_ = "base_link";
global_transform_.stamp_ = transform_in->header.stamp;
global_transform_.setRotation(q);
global_transform_.setOrigin(p);

broadcaster_.sendTransform(global_transform_);

geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose;
pose.pose.position.x = p.x();
pose.pose.position.y = p.y();
pose.pose.position.z = p.z();
pose.pose.orientation.x = q.x();
pose.pose.orientation.y = q.y();
pose.pose.orientation.z = q.z();
pose.pose.orientation.x = q.w();

path_.header.frame_id = "world";
path_.header.stamp = transform_in->header.stamp;
path_.poses.push_back(pose);

path_pub_.publish(path_);
```

Surprisingly,  the outcome of the orientation in RViz is different for the two corresponding frames even though I have used the same quaternion value for both (please see the image attached below).

Any idea what is causing this?

[image: RViz Frames]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315097/different-outcome-for-the-same-quaternion-between-geometry_msgs::pose-and-tf::transform/) by [Albtech](https://answers.ros.org/users/5273/albtech/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it's just a typo :

```
pose.pose.orientation.x = q.x();
pose.pose.orientation.y = q.y();
pose.pose.orientation.z = q.z();
pose.pose.orientation.x = q.w();
```

Should be :

```
pose.pose.orientation.x = q.x();
pose.pose.orientation.y = q.y();
pose.pose.orientation.z = q.z();
pose.pose.orientation.w = q.w();
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albtech](https://answers.ros.org/users/5273/albtech/) on 2019-02-08**:
Thanks a lot.